# Is Killer Bee still alive?

Tags: boruto

In Boruto: Naruto the Movie we see Hachibi being extracted out of Killer Bee, and he is presumed to be dead. Killer Bee's chakra resulted in much less pills than what was anticipated. I didn't give it much thought as it was clear that Momoshiki was used to consuming much more chakra pills.

But this time in the anime, Hachibi was sucked in by Momoshiki completely in tailed beast form .

**TL;DR**
Could Killer Bee have slipped past Momoshiki and Kinshiki like he did to Sasuke in Shippuden, considering that Kinshiki is somewhat of a sensory type?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Yes. Killer B is still alive.**

If you watch the full movie, *including the credits*, you'll see Gyūki (8-Tails) pulling him out of the water. As also mentioned on Wikia: [Killer B: Boruto The Movie](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Killer_B#Versus_Momoshiki_Arc)

> After they finished extracting Gyūki's chakra and throwing an unconscious B into a river to let him drown, Momoshiki commented that he was unimpressed with the tailed beast's power, as he could only produce a few small red pills with it.

The little size of chakra pills foreshadow that the attempted extraction of Gyūki failed and hence Killer B lived. This is confirmed during the credits.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure he is still alive because if he died they probably would have made it clear since Killer Bee is an important character. So, I would assume he is still alive since it didn't say anything about Killer Bee dying...

Answer (score 0):

Killer bee is most likely alive because Momoshiki didnt extract all of the 8 tailed so therefore Killer bee is still alive